# Magento 2.4.5 Module Wordpres What to do when you see curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate error?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.5, adobe-commerce

Install module wordpress-rest-api-client Magento 2.4.5

https://github.com/varsitynewsnetwork/wordpress-rest-api-client

**Error 1:**

- vnn/wordpress-rest-api-client 1.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.3) does not satisfy that requirement.

**Error 2:**

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://novedades.pcarts.com//wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories%5B0%5D=36&orderby=date&order=desc&per_page=5&page=1&image_display=1&image_size=medium_large

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

**Error 1:** -ignore-platform-reqs

warp composer vnn/wordpress-rest-api-client --ignore-platform-reqs install

**Or** in file composer.json

**Change:** "require": {"php": "^7.0"}, **to**  "require": {"php": "^7.1 || ^8.0"}

**Error 2:** create patch

Create file m2-hotfixes/wordpress-errorssl.patch

```
--- a/vendor/vnn/wordpress-rest-api-client/src/Http/GuzzleAdapter.php
+++ b/vendor/vnn/wordpress-rest-api-client/src/Http/GuzzleAdapter.php
@@ -43,6 +43,6 @@
      */
     public function send(RequestInterface $request)
     {
-        return $this->guzzle->send($request);
+        return $this->guzzle->send($request,['verify' => false]);
     }
 }
```

In Console:

php ./vendor/bin/ece-patches apply

**Or**

php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools patch